# Slidershow on fullsized photos after clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to add a simple slidershow with left-right nav arrows on multiple photos when one of photo is clicked and appears resized to browser window.

Know only that I'm supposed to do it with jQuery or raw js. 
Any ideas appreciated.

Attached a photo with autosized image after clicked describing the problem. The dotted lines defines the area where nav-arrows should works.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUWPr.jpg)

I've already wrote some code for clickable image in django template.

```
{% for i in '12345'|make_list %}
    {% with 'mainapp/photo_'|add:i|add:'.jpg' as image_static %}
        <div class="detail-image">
            <a href="{% static image_static %}">
                <img src="{% static image_static %}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```